# Android BLE connect discoonect issue after multiple connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am getting issues after I do multiple connect disconnect from same phone. Seems to be problem with the bluetooth stack. It does not connect after a specific amount of connect disconnect. Have any one faced the issue?

1. Android 4.3 > arround 25-30 try it will stop working
2. Android 4.4 > 6-7 try it will stop

I will call below to connect and disconnect. In between I do readCharacterestics.

Am I missing something?

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
```

Comment: Do you see anything in an **unfiltered** logcat?  Typically the bluetooth stack is *very* talkative.  When it fails, what seems to reset the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try with property

> autoConnection = false

it will improve re-connection time sequence.

check here [@Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt%28android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback%29)